# iTunes App getting rejected

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

My app has a login screen where the user logins. We are able to login on iPhone4, iPod 4, iPad 2 and iPhone5 simulator. But when we submit it to the iTunes store that time the app gets rejected. Apple mentioned that they were unable to login in the app.

I have HMAC-SHA 256 encryption for password and at the time of login i send the encrypted password. So is there anything that, Apple has implemented for iPhone5 which dont allow the services to accept encrypted data.

I don't have a iPhone5 and i don't want to buy a iPhone5 as its too expensive. Can anyone help me with this.

This is my code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = 
[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];

    
    //do post request for parameter passing 

    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    
    //set the content type to JSON

    [theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[theRequest addValue:userName forHTTPHeaderField:@"Username"];

[theRequest addValue:sha256(passWord) forHTTPHeaderField:@"Password"];
```

[image]

Below are comments from Apple:

> We found that your app exhibited one or more bugs, when reviewed on
>   iPhone 5 running iOS 6.0.1, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks, which
>   is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Comment: You need to provide more feedback from Apple as to what is not in compliance or what the bugs are. They should have provided you with reproducible steps.

Comment: These are only the steps, put the username and password and hit the login button.

Comment: I'm gonna need to see some code, instead of an image of the UI.

Comment: I just create a NSMUtableURLRequest object set POST, content type to "application/json" and add the username and password(SHA256 Encrypted) parameter in header.

Comment: try to search someone who have iphone5 and can do some testing and feedback for you...

Comment: Did you provide test username and password? And also, did you check that the web-service you are connecting works in California? :)

Comment: Did you test the App with the iPhone 5 simulator? I guess it's just about layout problems with the bigger screen.

Comment: Make sure you also handle the login correctly when you do not have internet.

Comment: @FahriAzimov: Ya i have provided them with test username and password. And the web-service is working here in India, i didn't tried it in California.

Comment: So, the problem maybe with your web-service, maybe it's not working in California, or maybe, as @Andrea explained, try your app with difficult network conditions, and, catch network errors such, connection time out. Good Luck ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm always in doubt when I hear about problem with different devices, more when there is network stuff in them. Have you ever tried your app in difficult network condition? are you handling network timeouts correctly? are you using a queue to correctly dispatch all the requests? are you sure that concurrent requests respond as you expect? 
You could use the Network Link Conditioner you can download it for free from Apple site and test worst cases. I know that these are just points, but I hope they could help you.
Ciao,
andrea

[UPDATE]
Did you add reachability class??????

Answer (score 0):

Apple changed NSURLRequest for iOS 6.0 in at least one way that breaks existing apps and code (I consider this a major bug, and it's been logged with Apple).

Have you tested on the iOS 6.0 simulator? I've seen a few apps that worked for years stop working on iOS 6 because of Apple's code changes.

(the main one I've seen is that the request is never sent from the phone, and so it timesout after approx 60 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

We suffered the same REJECTION recently(3/24/2015), our solution is not perfect, but hope it may guide a way to help people solving this kind of problem.

The comments from Apple are:

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad
>   running iOS 8.2 and iPhone running iOS 8.2 on both Wi-Fi and cellular
>   networks.
>   Please run your app on a device to identify the issue(s), then revise
>   and resubmit your app for review.

Our app is a simple app which just download a file and open it on the Webview.

In our situation, I think we can't do much more and can't reproduce the bug, So we just adjust the code by doing 2 things below(then success made the app turn to "Ready for Sale"):

> 1.Add an "Activity Indicator" to notify user the file download process are still proceed.
>   2.setConnection timeoutInterval to handle the waiting time.